# How to Set a Hexagonal Map into Perspective in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, perspective

I have created a hexagonal grid in inkscape:

[image]

Now I want to reshape the hexagonal grid such that it fits into the second shape. This way I would kind of get a 3D perspective.

I tried the following:

1. Select the hexagonal grid
2. Select the sheet, which are actually 4 lines that I have grouped together
3. Click Extensions --> Modify Path --> Perspective

Unfortunately this does not work, it yields the error message:

The second selected object is a group, not a path.
Try using Object->Ungroup.

I cannot just ungroup the lines, because I want to fit the grid into the sheet and not onto a single line. I was really thinking this would work.

Well, anyways, I'm a newbie, so I was hoping somebody here could help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inkscape 1.0 and later has a Perspective Envelope LPE (Live Path Effect). It works on groups. Not all paths effects do, but this one does. If you want to turn it back into paths afterwards, you can do *Path > Object to Path*.

Example

[image]

Comment: that's great, thx a lot for your answer, Billy!